# floating toc in distill for R

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

A floating TOC is not available for R's [{distill}](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/) package. See feature requests for it on GH [here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/366) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/341).

A minimal example of a distill article is below:

```
---
title: "min examp"
output: 
  distill::distill_article:
    toc: true
---

# header 1

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext

## header 2

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
```

Can we force the TOC to float and stay in the left hand side bar as you scroll down the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick hacky soluton with some CSS:

```
---
title: "min examp"
output: 
  distill::distill_article:
    toc: true
---

<style>
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
d-article {
    contain: none;
  }
#TOC {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  background: #ebebeb;     /* or   background: white; */
  padding: 10px;           /* optional */
  border-radius: 5px;      /* optional */
  }

/* Hide the ToC when resized to mobile or tablet:  480px, 768px, 900px */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
#TOC {
    position: relative;
  }
}
</style>

# header 1

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
etc...
```

Output (full screen):
[image]

Displayed on resized window:
[image]

Essential to/for this hack was to disable the predefined layout style:
[image]

I hope this will be of some help.

::: UPDATE FEB 2022 :::
I came up with hacky solution for my use case (applied to single article).
Here is [live example](https://radovan-miletic.github.io/distill-blog/posts/2022-01-24-the-toc-in-distill/) with code included. While we wait for a solution from {distill} [authors](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/distill/authors.html), you may feel tempted to try it. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is along the right path! Thanks also for acknowledging the limitation in the resized window. I think it would be nice to have default behavior hide the toc when resized to mobile or tablet. Is that something you know off the top of your head?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media?) rule.

Comment: Looking good! I'm ready to accept this, but while I have you here, do you know how to implement a [scrolling active state](https://css-tricks.com/sticky-table-of-contents-with-scrolling-active-states/), such that the TOC responds to the header the user is currently on? I'll give a total 150 reputation if you can also hack that into the solution, and I think the solution will be useful to others as well.

Comment: Made effort, but failed. Nevertheless, I updated with `scroll-behavior: smooth`. I have found this R Markdown [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/539), and it seems that [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/) Navigation has been already implemented thru the `toc_float` parameter and its options `collapsed` and `smooth_scroll`. Unfortunately, they are disabled in `distill`.

Comment: Thanks @RadovanMiletić for the great workaround! Having some trouble with the `scroll-beahvior: smooth` parameter, in my implementation smooth scroll does not actually scroll all the way to the anchor link - rather, the scrolling is choppy (on Chrome). Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AyushNoori. I just tried with the latest version of Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and it runs smoothly (check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) for browser compatibility). Also, I'm running on R 4.0.5 for Windows, RStudio 1.4.1698, and rmarkdown 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/basics.html) says that the toc floats automatically. It's not working for me though (Firefox).

Explicitly setting `toc_float: true` also does not help. Compared to `toc_float: false` it moves the toc over to the left but it is not floating for me in Firefox.

```
---
title: "min examp"
output: 
  distill::distill_article:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```

Looking into the Javascript Console with the page inspector shows that there is an error when loading some javascript library. That might be the issue causing this.

Comment: That's right, I've also been down this road. This feature isn't supported yet, but there are two feature requests for it on GH [here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/366) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/341). One idea is to use `headroom.js`.

Comment: Oh, I assumed "float" automatically means that the toc moves with the content, since that is how it works for regular RMarkdown. In the case of distill float seems to simply mean float as in the css float property.

Comment: That's right. toc_float is true by default. This would be an awesome feature if added!

Comment: Late to the party. Working on a distill webpage myself I stumbled here as well. The option `toc_float` defines - currently - whether the toc is displayed in the gutter or in the top part of the article, i.e. `toc_float: false`  will cause it to stay "on top". Thus, you can use the hack proposed above (Kudos to Radovan) or wait for the update / github request to be implemented.